Adding space after headings in officedown::rdocx_document
The resulting word document has text that is too close to the headings and sub-headings; how could I add more space?
E.g. by setting some option in the YAML header.

you need to set up the Word template according to your need and reuse the template with officedown

As David suggested, making a Word document setting the right options and then using
output:  
  officedown::rdocx_document:
    reference_docx: template.docx

did the trick.
